FastAPI Swagger UI authentication: "Authorize" button not handling verification
I am integrating authentication using Oauth2 and Okta, in my project using FastAPI. In Swagger UI, the "Authenticate" button is not authenticating the token.
The same thing is working on API level, but not on the main "Authorize" button. Even if I specify a wrong token, it is saying "authenticated".
This is where I am sending an invalid token:

This is where, it is authenticating, even with invalid token:

The code to support this authentication is: okta_authentication.py
import base64
import requests

from fastapi import HTTPException, Request
from starlette import status

from app.core.runtime_config import runtime_config
from app.services import secretsmanager


def fetch_okta_client_creds_from_sm():
    creds = secretsmanager.SecretsManager().retrieve_okta_creds(runtime_config.is_test_env)
    return creds


def generate_swagger_description() -> str:
    """
    Function to generate the swagger description for the Okta authentication.
    Returns:
        str: The swagger description.
    """

    okta_url = str(runtime_config.okta_url)
    okta_client_id = fetch_okta_client_creds_from_sm()[0]
    app_name = "data-persistence-infrastructure"
    redirect_uri = (
    f"{str(runtime_config.redirect_url_prefix)}/data/v1/infrastructure/misc/auth/callback"
)

    href = f"{okta_url}/authorize? response_type=token&scope=openid%20email%20profile&state=service_user&nonce={app_name}&client_id={okta_client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&sessionToken=&audience={okta_client_id}"
    desc = (
    '<a href="'
    + href
    + '" target="_blank"><b>Click here</b></a> to log in '
    + "to Okta and get your "
    "access token.<br/>" + "Copy and paste the token into the box below."
    )
    return desc


def get_token_from_request(request: Request) -> str:
    """
    Function to extract the token from the request.
    Parameters:
        request (Request): The request object.

    Returns:
        str: The access token.
    """

    auth = request.headers["Authorization"]
    token = auth.split(" ")[1]
    return token


 def fetch_user_details(request: Request) -> dict:
    """
    Function to fetch the user details from the Okta user info endpoint.
    Parameters:
        request (Request): The request object.

    Returns:
        user_details (dict): User details from token.
    """

    auth = request.headers["Authorization"]
    headers = {"Authorization": auth}
    response = requests.get(runtime_config.user_info_url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK:
        return response.json()
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid User")


 def encode_string_to_base64(string: str) -> str:
    """
    Function to encode a string to base64.
    Parameters:
        string (str): The string to encode.

    Returns:
        str: The base64 encoded string.
    """

    string_bytes = string.encode("ascii")
    base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(string_bytes)
    base64_string = base64_bytes.decode("ascii")
    return base64_string


 def call_introspect_api(token: str) -> bool:
    """
    Function to call the Okta introspect API to validate the access token.
    Parameters:
        token (str): The access token.

    Returns:
        bool: True if the token is valid, False otherwise.
    """

    okta_creds = fetch_okta_client_creds_from_sm()

    base_64_code = encode_string_to_base64(":".join([okta_creds[0], okta_creds[1]]))
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Basic {base_64_code}"}
    data = {"token": token, "token_type_hint": "id_token"}
    response = requests.post(runtime_config.okta_introspect_url, headers=headers, data=data)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()["active"]
    else:
        return False


 def verify_access_token(request: Request) -> str:
     """
     Function to verify the access token and return the user email.
     Parameters:
        request (Request): The request object.

    Returns:
        str: The user email.
    """

    # Extract the token from the request
    token = get_token_from_request(request)
    user_info = fetch_user_details(request)
    email = user_info["email"]
    resp = call_introspect_api(token)
    if not resp:
        raise HTTPException(
        status_code=401, detail="Invalid Request. Please Re-authenticate before proceeding"
    )
    return email

I am calling this in a middleware:
import logging

from fastapi import Request
from fastapi.security import HTTPBearer
from starlette.middleware.base import BaseHTTPMiddleware

from app.common.okta_authentication import generate_swagger_description, verify_access_token


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

security = HTTPBearer(
scheme_name="Okta Authentication", description=generate_swagger_description()
)


class AuthMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    async def dispatch(self, request: Request, call_next):
        # Check if the request path requires authentication
        path_prefixes = ["/data/v1/infrastructure/clusters", "/data/v2/infrastructure"]
        auth_required = False
        for path in path_prefixes:
            if request.url.path.startswith(path):
                auth_required = True
                break

        if not auth_required:
            return await call_next(request)

        # Manually invoke the dependency, so that the request is processed by the security dependency.
        await security(request)

        # Extract the user email from the access token
        user_email = verify_access_token(request)
        request.state.user_email = user_email
        return await call_next(request)

I am also calling the description method in my router's init.py file: (snippet of the same is here)
 security = HTTPBearer(scheme_name="Okta Authentication", description=generate_swagger_description())

 api_router_without_auth = APIRouter()
 api_router = APIRouter(dependencies=[Depends(security)])

What am I missing here? Any help will be appreciated.


Even if I specify a wrong token, it is saying "authenticated".

This is by design, but I agree that this UI can be confusing.
Swagger UI's "Available authorizations" dialog is just a place where you input the auth token for use in subsequent API calls. This dialog does not validate the token on your backend. The idea is to be able to input both valid and invalid tokens to test positive and negative scenarios.

That's what I am confused about, I have added the integration to test for valid token and user in the middleware, it is still not able to authenticate

Just to clarify - do you mean the authentication does not work on the backend? In other words, when you make a request with a valid token (whether from Swagger UI, Postman, curl or another HTTP client), the API treats the request as unauthenticated?

The request is taken as valid in all scenarios. Even if I send a wrong token, the request is taken as valid (from Authenticate button). But, if I call the API which is dependent upon auth, it gives an error correctly. My assumption is that the middleware is not working for the button
